# Newton's Method for Nonlinear System with Constraints

Tags: numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, newton-raphson, inverse-problems

I have a local solution of a dynamical system $\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x}(t) = \mathbf{g}(t;\mathbf{A}),
\end{equation}
where $\bf{f},\bf{g}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are parameters.

I am currently trying to numerically solve the inverse problem of this, that is, solving for $\mathbf{A}$ given the time $t_0$ and the corresponding state $\mathbf{x}(t_0)$.

To do this , I derived the Jacobian, $J$, of the function $\mathbf{g}$ and applied the Newton's method:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}^{n+1} = \mathbf{A}^{n}-J^{-1}(\mathbf{g}(t_0;\mathbf{A}^n)-\mathbf{x}(t_0)).
\end{equation}

I have a problem solving this because some of the elements of $\mathbf{A}$ are phases, so they should be defined between $0$ and $2\pi$. Obviously, the formula above does not have such constraints.

I looked up on the Internet for this kind of Newton's method with constraints, but all I found were the ones for one variable or multivariate scaler functions (like $\mathrm{f}(x)=0$ and $\mathrm{f}(\mathbf{x})$, not $\mathrm{\mathbf{f}}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}$).

How do I formulate this vector function version of the problem with constraints and solve it numerically?

Comment: This problem can be handled also as a minimization process. $\min_{A}\|x(t_0)-g(t_0,A)\|$

Comment: If $\mathbf A$ are phases, then there are infinitely many solution that differ by $2\pi$. Just normalize them after Newton's method find the normalized one. If the Newton's method converges. If it does not, then  the constraints on the phases are not the actual problems.

Comment: Phase is just one particular example I showed here. With unconstrained parameters, the solution can converge to an unexpected root if there is no good guess available for the initial value. In that case, we need some constraints to put the parameters in a certain range of values.